# Which is the oldest commentary on any of the scriptures?

Tags: scripture

Which is the oldest commentary on any of the scriptures mainly upanishads, any gita or any puranas or brahma sutras? When did the tradition of commenting texts start? Who is the commentator? It can be either available now or just referenced in some commentary available today.

Comment: The tradition of commenting on texts is also present in Buddhism. It is difficult to say where the tradition strated - in Buddhism or Hinduism or somewhere else. Bhartrprapancha was an earlier (than Shankara) commentator on the Brihadaranyaka upanishad, though I dont know when he lived.

Comment: Patanjali (2nd century BCE) wrote the Mahabhashya on Panini sutras, though the latter are not considered as scripture.

Comment: It would probably be Vedavyasa's commentary on Yoga Sutras of Patanjali.